# Image view not showing, but did select is working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collection view, but the image is not showing, the funny part is that the method didSelectItemAtIndexPath is working... what could be wrong? this is my cellForItemAtIndexPath code

```
cell *cell = [self.collectionPhotos dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CVCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *nombre =[self.arrayPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nombre]];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nombre];
return cell;
```

Comment: Have you verified that the "imageView" property is attached to the UIImageView object in your XIB?

Comment: yes it is, this problem is really strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do a bit more in-depth debugging.

Change this single line:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nombre];
```

to:

```
if(cell)
{
    UIImage * imageForCell = [UIImage imageNamed: nombre];
    if(imageForCell)
    {
        if(cell.imageView)
            cell.imageView.image = imageForCell;
        else
            NSLog( @"surprise, imageView is null" );
    } else {
        NSLog( @"can't find image named %@", nombre );
    }
 } else {
     NSLog( @"cell is null" );
 }
```

And see what happens.

Comment: it did not work, the collection view finds the image, and gets the name correctly, because when I use the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method, it works fine

Comment: Sure it gets the name correctly, but is "`imageForCell`" not null?  That's what my code change checks.  If you don't see "can't find image named" lines in your console, you should probably edit your question to show more code from your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" method.  Also, is "`cell`" not null?

Comment: that is all my code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and now I tried to put an image in the image view in the storyboard and is not showing it either... maybe is something wrong with the UIImageView

Comment: I added a few more lines of debugging.  Something is unexpectedly null, and that's why you are not seeing your image.

Comment: I get this message "surprise, imageView is null" what could be causing this ?

Comment: The cell you're using doesn't have an "`imageView`" property or outlet.

Comment: I erased the cell class, and created a new one, then I did the exact same thing as the first time and it worked... weird... Thanks